# Routing when using update_attribute with link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get the routing right when using link_to to update attribute through a controller:

view (@orders.each)

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', controller: :orders, action: 'cancel_order', id: order.id %>
```

OrdersController

```
def cancel_order
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @order.update_attribute(status: 0)
  redirect_to root_url
 end
```

No matter what I do with my routes, I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"cancel_order", :controller=>"orders", :id=>1}
```

Please help!

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: can you post your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**routes.rb**

**1st case**

```
resources :orders do
  member do
    get :cancel  #output path - cancel_orders/:id
  end
end
```

or
**2nd case**

```
get 'cancel_order/:id' => 'orders#cancel_order', as: :cancel_order
```

output path:  `cancel_order/:id`:

---

1 link:      `<%= link_to 'Cancel', cancel_orders_path(order) %>`

2 link:      `<%= link_to 'Cancel', cancel_order_path(order) %>`

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a shot. I am not sure which version of Rails are you using. Here is my code snippet

My `cancel_order` method

```
  def cancel_order
    @order = Order.find params[:id]
    @order.update_attributes status: true
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

My `show.html.erb`

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', cancel_order_order_path(@order), :method => :post %>
```

My `routes.rb`

```
  resources :orders do
    member do
      post 'cancel_order'
    end
  end
```

There are other way to achieve working routing but this feels cleaner to me. It would be easier to figure out your issue if you post your routes configuration. I hope this helps you.